# Do not have the required scopes for this request - Mixpanel

Tags: datasource, dashboard, mixpanel

I tried to use below `mixpanel API` for fetching event data.

[Link](https://mixpanel.com/api/2.0/events)

But I am facing a below `403 forbidden error`.

```
{
    "request": "/api/2.0/events",
    "error": "You do not have the required scope(s) for this request"
}
```

It seems to be like some permission is missing for accessing the API. But I can't able to find out where to set this scope

Please help me how to get rid of this error

Answer (score 0):

We've found success with the schema if you generate a Service Account from the Organization/Project Settings and use those credentials when authorizing the request.

To do this, go to your Organization Settings, click "+ Service Account" and use the credentials that are generated in the request you submit.